# How to remove empty pages in document class article

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking

Between sections/section or sections/subsection I have empty pages if a pre-section or pre-subsection does fill one page.
My document class:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{article}
```

How can I avoid this?
Thanks for help.

Here is the minimal example, which produces an emtpy page between chapter 1 and 2:

```
\begin{document}
\section{Chapter1}
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
x & y  \\ 
\hline
1 & 2  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\section{Chapter2}
\begin{figure}[H]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=1.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[angle=90]{figure.pdf}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If I change width to 1.3 or change angle to 0 there is no empty page between chapter 1 and 2.

Comment: What is a 'pre-section' exactly? \chapter{} <pre-section text> \section{} <non-presection text>?  I suspect a complete minimal example showing the problem will facilitate quicker and better solutions.

Comment: if your previous page contains a picture at the bottom it might be too large...

Comment: @jon: Yes, I meant before section (=pre-sectino). Sorry for the confusion. I added my mininal example in the question.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks for the hint. I suppose the problem is that the subsequent figure is too large.

Comment: With documentclass `article` you cannot have a `\chapter` command and also no `9pt`. Please provide a complete and running example.

Comment: Obviously, as Matin H. suspected, I had a picture which was too large (in the subsequent page and not previous). I suppose that the solution to avoid empty pages is to change the documents settings (less border) or to diminuish the size of the picture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `H` as a float specifier implies you're using the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float), which causes floats to stop floating or "really means "here" (and starts a new page first if necessary)" (see [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/5764)). So, you have two options:

1. Enlarge your document real estate using the [`geometry` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry). For example,

   ```
   \usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
   ```

   would increase the text block as far as is needed (in all directions) and leave only a `1cm` margin between the text block and the page boundary. This will allow you to fit more on a page, perhaps allowing the figure to be set where you want it to.

   Note that this option will have no effect if you're using a text block related length (like `\textwidth`), since the proportional modification would translate to the figure as well.
2. Modify the image dimensions to make it fit on the page. For example,

   ```
   \usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
   %...
   \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\includegraphics[angle=90]{figure}}
   ```

   would make sure that the resulting turned image fits within the `\textwidth` block. Of course, if it is taller than the text block, constraining the height would be more appropriate. Using

   ```
   \resizebox{!}{\textheight}{\includegraphics[angle=90]{figure}}
   ```

   in your case would *not* suffice, since the non-floating nature of an "`H`-figure" immediately after a `\section` causes LaTeX to keep them together. As such, you have less than `\textheight` to play with in terms of the figure height.